# How to customize axis when plot multiple time series data in 1 panel?

Tags: r, plot, axis, zoo

My situation is quiet like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919513/r-how-to-create-custom-x-axis-with-dates) question, how ever i need to plot multiple time series(or fixed length vectors) in one panel. (I want to upload a picture but it says i dont have enough reputation ...)

here's my sample code.

Column "id" identify a user. (sample code only has 1 user)
  Column "time" scale from 1 to 24*7 hours (hourly summary of 1 week)
  Column "A","B","C" are attributes summary hourly

```
> require(data.table)
# Create some data 
> dt<-data.table(id=rep(123,168),time=1:168,A=rnorm(168,10,5),B=rnorm(168,100,20),C=rnorm(168,10,5))
> dt
      id time         A         B         C
  1: 123    1  2.435577 147.01446 12.484723
  2: 123    2 15.119403  88.05115  7.226495
  3: 123    3 17.835930 110.01482  6.888222
  4: 123    4 10.455834 102.48860 13.098892
  5: 123    5  8.107672  83.70896  7.711350
 ---                                       
164: 123  164  8.301877 145.88020 10.195002
165: 123  165 12.403081  97.90534 14.249087
166: 123  166 16.563673 125.69398 11.039720
167: 123  167 11.091746  98.81823 15.131038
168: 123  168 10.190338  87.32466 11.422943
> z<-zoo(dt)
> plot(z[,3:5],yax.flip=TRUE,col=1:3) #plot all attributes timeseries in one panel
```

I would like to add grid and customize x-axis to be something like this:

Mon.,1,2,3,...,23,Tue.,1,2,3,...,23,Wed.,1,2,3,...,23,Thu.,1,2,3,...,23,Fri.,1,2,3,...,23,Sat.1,2,3,...,23,Sun.,1,2,3,...,23

I tried to use `axis`, `abline` and `grid` to get what i want but it simply won't work.(it works fine if `plot.type=single`)

Comment: Try setting `xaxt="n"` in your original `plot` call, then use `axis` to add the axis as you desire.

Comment: @Thomas i tried that but it didnot work, @P Lapointe 's method is the right way to go. I have checked the ?plot.zoo again and it does said "Axis can be used within the panels themselves but not outside the panel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `panel` option in `plot.zoo`. This allows you to add the grid to all panels. And you can also add the bottom axis to the last panel in the plot. I didn't put every hour numbers because it would have been too crowded.

```
ax.date <-as.POSIXlt("2013-01-06")+(0:167)*3600 #Dummy date for POSIXlt method

my.panel <- function(x, y, ..., pf = parent.frame()) {
 grid(NA,NULL)
 abline(v=seq(1,168,24),col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted", lwd = par("lwd"))
 lines(x, y, ...)

 #if bottom panel
 if (with(pf, length(panel.number) == 0 ||
        panel.number %% nr == 0 || panel.number == nser)) {
      # create ticks at x values and then label every 24th tick
      axis(side = 1, at = x, labels = FALSE, tcl=-0.3) #hour ticks
      axis(side = 1, at = seq(1,168,6), labels = FALSE) #6hour ticks ticks
      axis(1,at=seq(1,168,24), labels=format(ax.date[seq(1,168,24)],"%a")) #day of the week
      axis(1,at=seq(13,168,24),labels=format(ax.date[seq(13,168,24)],"%H"), cex.axis=0.7) #noon ticks
   }
 }
 plot(z[,3:5], panel = my.panel,yax.flip=TRUE,col=1:3,xaxt="n")
```

[image]

Comment: That's Great!Thanks! is there a way to make vertical grid more dense?

Comment: I edited my post to add vertical gridlines at the beggining of the day. Basically, the grid call becomes: `grid(NA,NULL)` and I add vertical ablines: `abline(v=seq(1,168,24),col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted", lwd = par("lwd"))`